# URL (string) equivalents for cURL commands?

Tags: javascript, php, curl

I'm looking through an API, and all the examples are given using [cURL](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html). I don't use cURL myself, and am looking for equivalent URL strings that I can send as GET arguments.

For example, say the cURL command is this:

```
$ curl -X GET "https://thesite.com/api/orgs" \
       -u "NEekIy8ngCpv8TbOjrliapP0D1Bu9SN9:"
```

What would be the equivalent URL string to this? Something that could be copied and pasted into a browser, and would return the appropriate JSON response. Something like:

`https://thesite.com/api/orgs?user=NEekIy8ngCpv8TbOjrliapP0D1Bu9SN9` ??

The [cURL docs](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) say that `-u` is `user:password`, which is why I figured that the GET variable(s) for the previous cURL command were `user=NEekIy8ngCpv8TbOjrliapP0D1Bu9SN9` (and `password=` ?)

Is this the right conversion? No matter where I look, I can't find an equivalency chart anywhere. Even a quick code I could write in PHP or JS to create a cURL object, and then return the formatted URL string would suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is related to the Authorization HTTP header and [HTTP Authentication](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Authentication), which will contain the username and the password. But this username is not a GET parameter, it goes into an HTTP Header, so it cannot be used it in the query string (?user=...).

The string equivalent to this, that should work when put into an address bar of a browser is :

```
user:password@thesite.com/api/orgs
```

If you use

```
user@thesite.com/api/orgs
```

You will be prompted for a message box asking for username and password.

This works if the method from server side is "basic" or "digest". There are plenty of other auth methods used. As I'm not specialized in this topic, I cannot tell you if it will always work.

Also have a look at this last note on the linked page :

> The use of these URLs is deprecated. ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) it does the same as curl

Code example:

```
<?php
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');
echo $homepage;
?>
```

To send $_POST and $_GET requests you can use [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/

Code example:

```
<?php

    $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/user', [
        'auth' => ['user', 'pass']
    ]);
    echo $res->getStatusCode();
    // "200"
    echo $res->getHeader('content-type');
    // 'application/json; charset=utf8'
    echo $res->getBody();
    // {"type":"User"...'

    // Send an asynchronous request.
    $request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org');
    $promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
        echo 'I completed! ' . $response->getBody();
    });
    $promise->wait();

?>
```

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't answer my question. I'm not looking for a PHP equivalent, I'm looking for the string equivalent. And if you're going to show an example, at least use the same one from my question, with the `-u` contents. This answer is just fishing for more reputation on SO.

Comment: Read my answer update I add more info about how to send post and get requests using guzzle

Comment: Thank you for the updates. I appreciate you including something with the authentication parameters. I'm still interested in exactly what the GET-formatted URL string looks like. It isn't a POST request, so there should be a tangible string that I could (in theory) copy and paste in a browser, and receive a valid response.